# Pro Webmasters Chat Room

Tags: discussion, beta-progress, chat

I've [created a room](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153/pro-webmasters) on the new Stack Exchange chat system for anyone who wants to join. To enter, you must:

- Have at least 20 reputation on [meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)
- Be logged into meta.stackoverflow.com

The room is for discussing anything and everything about the Pro Webmasters site. Its also a neat place to meet and talk to the people who have been answering your questions, yell at the moderators or just lurk. Hopefully we also discuss things surrounding the site.

**Edit**

If most people who would normally be in chat prefer IRC, I don't see any reason why we *can't* set up a moderated channel on freenode. In fact, if you'd like to do that, feel free.

I used the new chat system because:

- It ties in quite nicely with Stack Exchange sites. Links to questions / etc are boxed, markdown is supported.
- We know users are who they say they are because they are authenticated via OpenID instead of nickserv. Don't be surprised if you see JeffAtwood (authenticated by nickserv) in IRC. If you do, rest assured that it is *not* Jeff Atwood.
- Stack Exchange went through all of the trouble of , well, making it.

Answer (score 2):

For info, [chat.stackexchange](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) is now avaible; please feel free to use this for all your chatting needs. There is a "chat" link at the top of all Q&A pages on the main site.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, i think an IRC Network would be better. So people can use Bouncers or Screen with irssi. But chat rooms which needs an open Browser Tab, got - so are my experiences - almost not so many users.

But the idea behind is nice. So thank for creating. :-)

Comment: I wouldn't mind using IRC either. See updates